# Selecting last item in multiselect with angularjs and md-options

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have the following code

```
<md-select multiple ng-model="filtered" placeholder="Select a team member" ng-show="onTeam">
      <md-option ng-value="opt.value"  ng-repeat="opt in allowedStatuses" selected="{{ opt.value === opt.last ? 'selected' : '' }}">{{ opt.title }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

I would like the last option to always be selected. How to do this?

Comment: Should also add, that almost any combonation simply selects everything in the list

Answer (score 0):

Answer was this...

```
    <md-select multiple ng-model="filtered" placeholder="Select a team member" ng-show="onTeam">
        <md-option ng-value="opt.value"  ng-repeat="opt in allowedStatuses" ng-selected="{{ opt.title == 'Myself' }}">{{ opt.title }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
```

Needed the `ng-selected` in there instead of `selected`...